# Best compression format for backing up many MacOS files (7Z, GZIP, BZIP2, etc)?

Tags: macos, backup, compression

I want to take a backup of the folder `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync` which houses my iOS Backups on my MacOS computer.

To do the backup, I'm planning on archiving this folder with file compression, using the application [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/). However, I am unsure which file compression format is suitable for this (e.g. 7Z, GZIP, BZIP2, etc) – and what are the appropriate settings for the selected format.

My objectives are:

1. To make the archive reliable for extraction in the future.
2. To make it take up as little space as possible, however with reliability (1. above) being the most important objective.

What is the appropriate file compression format for backups of MacOS files – also considering MacOS metadata – given these objectives, and what are the appropriate settings – e.g. should I use "Solid Archive" or not?

---

NB: Keka currently seems to support the formats: 7Z, ZIP, TAR, GZIP, BZIP2, XZ, LZIP, BROTLI, ZSTD, LRZIP, AAR, WIM, DMG, ISO

Comment: None of those support macOS metadata - However I don't think that there is any for the MobileSync directory. I also think the backups are encrpted so can't be compressed. All those methods are reliable. So just see whioch one works best for you

Comment: Does using Disk Utility or hdiutil to create a disk image (dmg) from a folder work for you? By default, it uses compression.

Comment: Right click on folder and choose compress. Makes zip which includes metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: If you've selected the option to *encrypt* your iOS backups, they won't compress.*

*Additional note: if your backup is mainly composed of already-compressed media (photos and videos), they won't compress well.*

Otherwise, your best bet is either lrzip, 7zip, or xz. I don't know how big each of your backups are, but if it's, say, 2-3GB, you can likely try each of the options. The best option is dependent on the type of data - you won't know unless you test it. In general, I'd recommend using 7zip. It seems to go decently quick and offers fairly good compression. xz typically gives comparable compression to 7zip. lrzip takes considerably more time, uses considerably more RAM, but typically has the best compression.

Other formats such as zip, bzip2, and gzip are older and don't provide the best amount of compression.

Comment: Thanks for good information. I have encrypted my iOS backups, so good to know that compression will have little effect. For the record, I compared 7zip to normal zip compression via the MacOS Context Menu, and zip resulted in the smallest file size and is arguably a bit easier to perform.